# Python 2 to 3 = TypeError: descriptor 'find' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'bytes' object

Tags: python-2to3

Hello we try to convert python 2 to 3 but we are stuck with an error.
Maybe someone has an idea.

Thanks

```
if episode_num is not None:
                        episode_num = str.encode(str(episode_num), 'ascii','ignore')
                        if str.find(episode_num, ".") != -1:
                            splitted = str.split(episode_num, ".")
                            if splitted[0] != "":
                                #TODO fix dk format
                                try:
                                    season = int(splitted[0]) + 1
                                    is_movie = None # fix for misclassification
                                    if str.find(splitted[1], "/") != -1:
                                        episode = int(splitted[1].split("/")[0]) + 1
                                    elif splitted[1] != "":
                                        episode = int(splitted[1]) + 1
                                except:
                                    episode = ""
                                    season = ""
```

if str.find(episode_num, ".") != -1:

TypeError: descriptor 'find' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'bytes' object

https://www.dropbox.com/s/viszyzlpbl92yj0/source.py?dl=1

Comment: In your own words, why are you trying to use the function `str.find` from the class, rather than just calling a *method* on `episode_num`? And why are you trying to `.encode` the string in the first place?

Comment: Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and make sure you understand the differences between how 2.x and 3.x handle bytes objects vs. strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 is much more strict about mixing `str` and `bytes` strings.  Just be consistent.  When you use `encode` you create a `bytes` string.

```
if bytes.find(episode_num, b".") != -1:
```

Better, learn to use `in`:

```
if b"." in episode_num:
```